# sf::Shader and sf::RectangleShape

Tags: c++, sfml

I have a question about using the `sf::Shape` from the SFML graphic library. In my game i use `sf::RectangleShapes`. For example the UserInterface or the player. Here is a peace of code:

```
std::unique_ptr<sf::RectangleShape> rect;
sf::RenderTarget &target;
sf::RenderStates &stats;

void SfUIComponents::SfBaseRectangle::draw()
{
        target.draw(*rect, stats);
}
```

When I load the shader with a file like here:

```
If(shader->loadFromFile(vertex, fragment)){ loaded = true;}

effect->loadFromFile("wave.vert","blur.frag");
```

Before I draw the rectangle :

```
void SfShader::activate()
{
    stats.shader = shader;
}
```

The text which I draw too show the effect but the rectangles aren't visible. So ms question without showing more code. Is it possible to use the sfml shader for rectangles which are simple fill with white color?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the shader when drawing into your render.
You can do this by creating a "sf::RenderState", and setting it's shader:

```
sf::RenderState rs;
sf::Shader effect;

effect.loadFromFile("wave.vert","blur.frag");

rs.shader = &effect;

window.draw(rect , rs);
```

If you don't need to use more information from the RenderState (like a texture), you can directly pass the shader to the draw function:

```
sf::Shader effect;

effect.loadFromFile("wave.vert","blur.frag");

window.draw(rect , &effect);
```

Comment: I have tried that but the rect is not visible. I have the solution about using "shader.SetTexture("image", image);" I give the rect a Texture and directly after loading and setting the texture. I use sf::Shader::currentTexture. Know it is possible. But thanks for your answer (: